# Unable to enrich exchange from aggregation route

Tags: apache-camel

I'm having an issue understanding why an aggregator is not receiving the right exchange from a sub route used to enrich the original exchange.
What I can say is that the log prints correctly at the end of the route but in the parent route I only get a message body from earlier on in the sub route.
With that said, here is an condensed excerpt of the routes.

```
this.from("direct:fetchPartnersForAggregation")
.to("sql:select * from ...")
.process(exchange -> {
List<Map<String, Object>> payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);
exchange.getIn().setHeader("numOfPartners", payload.size());
if(payload.size() < 1 || (payload.size() == 1 && payload.get(0).get("process_id")== null))
  exchange.getIn().setBody(null);
})
.choice()
.when(not(emptyBody))
    .split(body())
    .streaming()
    .setHeader("partner_id", simple("${body[process_id]}"))
    .to("sql:select ....")
    .setHeader(Constants.EXCHANGE_HEADERS.OBJECT_TYPE, simple("partners"))
    .to("log:partner_extracted?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
    .process(appIdCollator)
    .process(partnerBuilder)
    .aggregate(constant(true), partnersAggregator)
    .completionPredicate(new PartnerSizePredicate())
    .to("log:partners_collated?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")  //The log prints everything correctly
.end();


//In my other route:
...
.enrich("direct:fetchPartnersForAggregation", partnersAggregator).id("partners_added") <========== The 'newExchange' in this partnersAggregator contains the body returned in the first sql:Select in the aggregation route.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise that the splitter had it's own aggregation strategy build in which can be overridden according to [the odcumentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html#_split_aggregate_requestreply_sample). I simply moved my aggregator to override that and I now have the correct exchange:

```
this.from("direct:fetchPartnersForAggregation")
.to("sql:select * from ...")
.process(exchange -> {
List<Map<String, Object>> payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);
exchange.getIn().setHeader("numOfPartners", payload.size());
if(payload.size() < 1 || (payload.size() == 1 && payload.get(0).get("process_id")== null))
  exchange.getIn().setBody(null);
})
.choice()
.when(emptyBody)
    .stop()
.otherwise()
    .split(body(), partnersAggregator)
    .streaming()
    .setHeader("partner_id", simple("${body[process_id]}"))
    .to("sql:select ....")
    .setHeader(Constants.EXCHANGE_HEADERS.OBJECT_TYPE, simple("partners"))
    .to("log:partner_extracted?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
    .process(appIdCollator)
    .process(partnerBuilder)
    .to("log:partners_collated?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
.end();
```